# In android 2.3 camera preview show white screen on simulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera

In android 2.3 camera preview show white screen how to solve this issue?

Comment: Here's an issue for this in Google groups: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=13133

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working on Emulator this is normal. You have to configure your emulator properties to support camera. This can be done from Android SDK Manager. Select your emulator and in properties search for Camera property and enable it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
But in android 2.1 to 2.2 camera preview is look like black and white chess board but in android 2.3 it look simply white screen. So my question is what is problem with android 2.3?

Comment: Well, I am not sure what it is.May be Google might have changed the way the Camera preview looks. Need not worry.